# What is the minimal install footprint to be able to open a sln with a .CloudService

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk

I'm opening a solution which has a dependency on an outdated version of the Azure SDK such that Web PI wont install it.

This leaves me with the following error when I build the project:

> `WAT080 : Failed to locate the Microsoft Azure SDK. Please make sure the Microsoft Azure SDK v2.7 is installed.`

What's the least amount of

- steps I need to execute and
- junk I can put into my environment

to make it load in VS and compile?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the archived downloads page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

1. Follow the trail via the appropriate *Azure SDK for .NET* (As of Mar 2017, [v2.7.1 is here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178))
2. Click the download button
3. Select `MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi`
4. Select `MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi` <- x86 is not useful
5. Select `MicrosoftAzureTools.VS140.exe` <- 14:- VS 2015

I downloaded and installed each separately

*HACK: My installation of VS2015 was slightly mangled, so I was still seeing a message from VS offering to install the 2.7 tools. I was able to get over that by installing the latest (2.9 at time of writing) tools, whereupon I got a clean build. I'll be doing a clean reinstall of VS and will research whether that can be avoided*

Comment: Hi Ruben. Please do you think you could take at look a this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198294/how-to-configure-ninject-so-that-it-creates-a-single-instance-per-controller?noredirect=1#comment67673663_40198294

Comment: @eddy I see what you did there ;) nice!